# Large range delay at medium frequency for MC

Tags: programming, uart, delay

I have a program that varies the step time and duty cycle for a 6 step commutation sequence.  It takes an 8-bit ADC result and stores it as the TMR0 value, when TMR0 overflows, the ISR selects the next sequence.

I have 2 problems:

1. This only works at low INTOSC frequencies, where UART will not work, and
2. I don't get a large enough step range.

Any general ideas on how to create a larger ranged delay at a higher frequency?  My first idea is to use a nested loop, still using a TMR0 value, then putting that inside of a loop the steps the inverse of TMR0 times...

Comment: What microcontroller platform? Which toolchain?

Comment: pic18 & breadboard

Comment: Can you give us a rough indication of the relationship you need between ADC value and step rate? From the sounds of it, it's step frequency = k/(255-ADC). What is the value of k?

Comment: sure, if I'm looking for 302.5 RPM, I get 5.04 RPS * 12 poles = 60 Hz, so k = .0166.  This gives me my delay in uS, which could be plugged into a delay_uS function, but I'd like to use a timer/ counter so as not to waste cycles.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the example you gave. So 60Hz = 0.0166 / (255-254.9997). That can't be right because an 8-bit ADC can't give a value of 254.9997.  Sorry to be picky about this, but if I can understand it, then I can give you a good answer.

Comment: Also, what range of steps per second do you need. What is the maximum and minimum ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach the problem would be to introduce some additional variables that keep track of the timer interval and how many times it's been called so that a fixed number of interrupts may be ignored. For example the following C pseudo-code to slow the execution time down by a factor of 10.

```
uint_8 ticks_left, timer_interval;

void my_isr()
{
    ticks_left--;
    if (ticks_left == 0)
    {
         disable_timer();
         // Move to next ADC etc
    } else
         setup_timer(timer_interval);
    }
}

void main()
{
    timer_interval = your_calculated_value;
    ticks_left = 10;
    setup_timer(timer_interval);
}
```

It won't be perfectly accurate because of the (probably less than 10 cycle) instruction delay between the interrupt and the new timer value being set, although if that's a concern you could check the assembler output to find the number of cycles it will take and reset the timer to a slightly lower value in the ISR if that's likely to be a problem.